# Oracle stack trace line number does not match source code!

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I got a stack trace from Oracle saying there was a problem on Line 299. No problem, I looked at that line in the package in question, and say that it's a line in an initialization block that sets a variable to 1, and does not call the procedure that raised the error.

It looks like there's a mismatch between what the server is executing and what I am seeing when I view the package source, based on the line number in the stack trace.

How I looked at the package: I used PL/SQL Developer and clicked "View Pacakge" on the package name in the object browser. When I looked at the same package in source control, an error on Line 299 makes sense (it's a call to the procedure that failed).

So my question is: WTF is going on? Why do I get source code that doesn't seem to match the stack trace line numbers when I ask Oracle for the pacakge source?

(oracle 10g)

Comment: @Mike Atlas: This is the first time it's happened to me and it's making me (and my fellow devs and DBA) question my sanity. I imagine there may be much face-palming when a solution is finally revealed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that my script was referencing `API_USR.SOME_PACKAGE` and I was logged in as `READONLY_USR` and `READONLY_USR` owns an older version of `SOME_PACKAGE`. When I viewed `API_USR.SOME_PACKAGE` via `READONLY_USR` I got the right source code.

*face-palm*

Comment: I usually get the wrong line number when using Oracle SQL Developer on simple queries (10-15 lines long) so at least you're past your problem now.

Comment: @Mike Atlas: I think in Oracle SQL Developer (and also probably in Allround Automation's PL/SQL Developer which is what I'm currently using) the line number returned is *relative to the first line of the query*. so that if you have 3 queries on the worksheet it may show Query3 begining on line 30 of the text file, but when you execute *only* Query3, Oracle sees it as starting at line 1 (because it doesn't know the query's position in the file).

Answer (score 1):

I think you already got the source of that package opened in PL/SQL developer. When you choose View Source again, it activates the previously opened editor, without reloading the source.

Comment: Hmm I closed all editors for that package (there was only one, which was opened the first time I tried to View Package). The I right-clicked the package in the Object Browse, and chose "Refresh". Then I right-clicked and chose View. Then I see the old code again! I wouldn't be surprised *at all* if it was a PL/SQL Developer quirk rather than Oracle, but I can't tell at this point...